# What tools are available to visualize in-class dependencies (e.g. for PHP)?

Tags: php, python, code-analysis

I am looking for an easy-to-use tool which can visualize the 'inner working' of a class, written e.g. in PHP. What I would like to see are the different class methods, and how they are related (method A calls method B etc). Is there such a tool to create such a graph?
In a further step, maybe there is a tool which also visualizes the 'inner working' of a class (in a reverse-engineering way) of really how the workflow is, i.e. with all `if-else` decisions etc, what methods are called in what case?

If anyone can refer me to such a tool (preferably for PHP and Python) I would appreciate it.

Comment: xhprof can generate such a chart of actual run use; but as calls can be dynamic - e.g. call_user_func() - it's hard to generate an accurate chart statically

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this tool, I guess it can be of some usefullness, when I have figured out how to fix the completly faulty example of `xhprof`...

Answer (score 2):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) is a tool which can create documentation as well as `call graphs` from your code.

You can refer this page for more info: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html

I use this tool to create documentation and call graphs. it is very powerful although output depends on preference.

It supports a number of languages such as C, Objective-C, C#, PHP, Java, Python, IDL (Corba, Microsoft, and UNO/OpenOffice flavors), Fortran, VHDL, Tcl, and to some extent D.

Comment: With the given configuration options for how to make doxygen create those graphs, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://phpcallgraph.sourceforge.net/ or this gist from github (https://gist.github.com/sebastianbergmann/625915)

Comment: I mentioned phpcallgraph below, and it would be great if it would work, but it does not. I want to analyze the code of exactly one file, and phpcallgraph raises an error in some other code. It seems the code is actually executed, which is NOT what I want. Also, the Version 0.8.0 has a bug one neesd to fix manually. gist (for ONE sourcefile) does not really show something. My file has various functions, but gist only shows one field. Not usable for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Although a lot of suggestions point towards `pycallgraph` and `phpcallgraph` I don't think these will do what you want to do - these are for runtime analysis, whereas what it sounds like you want to do static analysis.

I'm not aware of any tools for this, but, given that you're only interested in the workings of a single class and the relationships within that class, with a little effort you should be able to hack something together in your scripting language of choice which

1. Parses all function names and variable declarations inside the class and stores them somewhere
2. Uses the information from step 1 to identify variable usages, variable assignments and function calls, along with the functions in which these occur.
3. Convert this information into the graph format used by `dot` and then use dot to generate a directed graph showing dependencies.

Given the effort involved, if the class is not *too* large I would be tempted just to do it by hand!

Good luck, and if you do find a solution would love to see it.

Comment: "A little effort"?  If you don't care if the answer is junk, sure.  If you want a reasonably accurate answer, you need to capture classes, call-like-syntax (function calls, method calls, destructor calls, library calls, calls found in traits, ...) in all the ways it can occur, record namespaces, and resolve names to target classes/namespaces.  I think this is a lot more work then you do.  People incredibly underestimate what it takes to build a static analysis tool that produces useful results on non-toy codes.

Comment: @IraBaxter I get what you're saying, it isn't easy to be comprehensive. But the fact that this is only to operate on a single class (and understand relationships within that class) makes the problem a lot simpler. And furthermore, just identifying variable usages and function calls should give you most of what you're interested, if not quite everything.

Comment: "it isnt easy to be comprehensive" ... or accurate.  I don't see how restricting to a class really simplifies much.  Pretty much everything you can write outside a class, you can write inside, too, so what part of the problem have you eliminated?

Comment: Because you only have to identify variable references and function calls where the variable or function belongs to that class (identified in step 1 of the suggestion), and can ignore anything that depends on something outside of the class.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at [pycallgraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/) ?

Also, for runtime calls you could run the python code with cProfile and view it with [GProfToDot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot)

Comment: For PHP I have used http://xdebug.org/ in past. It provides profiling and creates callgrind like files. This can then be visualized using tool called KCacheGrind[link](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)

Comment: I cannot see how `xdebug` could be used for my purposes. I want to do a 'static' code analysis only in the form of `analyzer code.php > result`, i.e. without modifying the PHP code in question.

Comment: http://phpcallgraph.sourceforge.net/ is there for your purpose. I haven't used it though

Comment: I just found `phpcallgraph` myself, would be great if it would work, but it did not. I want to analyze the code of exactly one file, and `phpcallgraph` raises an error in some other code. It seems the code is actually executed, which is NOT what I want. Also, the Version 0.8.0 has a bug one need to fix manually.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried quick documentation with DoxyGen. It supports call graphs.